# Mage::getModel('index/process') returns false

Tags: php, magento, model

I call `Mage::getModel('index/process')` in data-upgrade script and it returns `false`. If i call `Mage::getModel('Mage_Index_Model_Process')` it returns object but then when i call `getCollection()` on this object this function returns `false`.
What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Magento are you using? Have you made any core modifications? Have you made any local modifications that override core?
 Which other modules do you have installed? Have you cleared your cache? So many questions!

Comment: 1.9, no, sure but not for this class and there is no modifications that overrides `getModel`, many modules wrote by our company and others, yep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my error. I wanted to add models to Index in local pool. I had such code in my config.xml:

```
<index>
    <class>MyModule_Index_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>index_resource</resourceModel>
</index>
<index_resource>
    <class>MyModule_Index_Model_Resource</class>
    <entities>
        <process_store_status>
             <table>mymodule_index_process_store_status</table>
        </process_store_status>
    </entities>
</index_resource>
```

And now Magento search for class `MyModule_Index_Model_Process` instead of `Mage_Index_Model_Process`. Despite i have no one line of code to rewrite that class. I changed my code to

```
<mymodule_index>
    <class>MyModule_Index_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>index_resource</resourceModel>
</mymodule_index>
<mymodule_index_resource>
    <class>MyModule_Index_Model_Resource</class>
    <entities>
        <process_store_status>
             <table>mymodule_index_process_store_status</table>
        </process_store_status>
    </entities>
</mymodule_index_resource>
```

Now everything works fine.